# Calling Json from other domain using callback

Tags: ajax, callback, getjson, arrays

I have a json array with a callback  returned by a web service and returns `?({"` and the json goes on.

I can call the json array using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var url =  "the url goes here ending with ?callback?";
    $.getJSON(url , null, function(data) {
        alert(data.length);
    });

    });
```

But the problem is that i always get undefined data length....

any suggestions?